# Django CMS search engine, few questions

Tags: django-cms

It's tough to find good documentation on this. I am trying to build a simple search engine for a very small Django CMS site built with CMS version 2.4. I have found out the best way is with Haystack + django-cms-search, which then tells me that package is deprecated and to use aldryn-search instead, the documentation is lacking big time.

From what I can gather, I need to create a search_indexes.py but where does this go? I thought this was app specific? If I am just using it to index Page model from the CMS, how do I go about integrating that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For cms versions < 3.0 then `django-cms-search` would be your solution, once you switch to >= 3.x then `aldryn-search` is the way to go.

The reason for this is that `aldryn-search` is basically a fork/refactor of `django-cms-search` targeting haystack 2.x and cms 3.x

I'm considering adding backwards compatibility for `aldryn-search` to work on cms 2.4 but to get you up and running, here's what you can do.

Install `django-cms-search` and add `haystack` and `cms_search` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

This should allow you to start indexing pages already, if not please post a traceback :).

Once you are able to index pages, now it's up to you if you want to manage the search page through the cms using an apphook or a fixed url.

Usually when working with search, one needs to tweak some things and add search specific templates, for this I highly recommend creating a `search` app in your project, add a `models.py` and then add this app to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Now back to the search page, if you choose to use an apphook, then in your search app, create a `cms_app.py` file and add the following:

```
from cms_search.cms_app import HaystackSearchApphook
apphook_pool.register(HaystackSearchApphook)
```

this registers the packaged apphook from `django-cms-search` with the cms (this used to happen by default, but not anymore).

Otherwise, if you chose to have a fixed url not managed by the cms, you can simply add a `urls.py` in your search app with the following:

```
from django.conf.urls import *

from haystack.views import search_view_factory

urlpatterns = patterns('search.views',
    url('^$', search_view_factory(), name='haystack-search'),
)
```

then in your project's `urls.py` you can include the `search.urls` under any name you want, like so:

```
url(r'^search/', include('search.urls')),
```